# Oracle.ManagedDataAccess 21.4.0 will not install

Tags: oracle, nuget-package, oracle.manageddataaccess

I have a web application in Visual Studio (VB.net) and I'm trying to install Oracle.ManagedDataAccess 21.4.0 via the Nuget Package Manager. The .NET Target Framework is 4.6.1 and I have System.Text.Json 5.0.2 installed via NuGet.

For some reason when I try to install it, it won't. Here's the output:

Install failed. Rolling back...

Package 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.21.4.0 : System.Text.Json [5.0.2, )' does not exist in project 'RuntestWeb'

Package 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.21.4.0 : System.Text.Json [5.0.2, )' does not exist in folder 'C:\SvnWebApp\packages'

Could not install package 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess 21.4.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

I see the Json installed in Nuget and the DLL in the references and I also see the folder under packages.

What gives?

Comment: "System.Text.Json [5.0.2]" sounds like you need .NET Framework version 5 or above.

Comment: That appears to me to be the version of System.Text.Json, not .NET.

Comment: Often the version number of assemblies are aligned to .NET Framework version. Anyway, meanwhile I googled and it really looks like Oracle.ManagedDataAccess 21.4.0 requires .NET Framework version 5

Comment: I ended up fixing it by installing an older version of the NuGet package (19.13.0 instead of 21.4.0) because I only have .NET 4.8 installed.